# Stages Power Left Compatibility with Shimano Sora

Tags: crankset, power

On my [Cube Attain Pro 2021](https://bike-review.co.uk/cube-attain-pro-road-bike-2021-review/) bike I have a [Shimano Sora FC-R3000](https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/component/sora-r3000/FC-R3000.html) crankset(175 mm - 50/34T).

Compatible with my budget, I'm planning on investing in a [Stages Power Left](https://stagescycling.com/en_us/product/power-meters/left-sided) power meter to get wattage data out of my rides.

My problem is which model from Stages to buy. I've checked their [generic compatibility page](https://support.stagescycling.com/en/support/solutions/articles/1000137517-how-can-i-find-out-if-my-bicycle-is-compatible-with-a-stages-power-meter-) which upon inspection technically it should be fine but I still don't know which exact model from Stages to go to. Yes, it will be a 175 mm one since that's my current crank length but since Sora isn't directly mentioned on their product listings which model should I buy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any Shimano *road* HollowTech II crank will work. Choose the cheapest in their line up which used to be 105, unless you plan to upgrade your group to (or upgrade to a bike with) EG Ultegra in the future and want parts to match visually.

The Road groups are Sora, Tiagra, 105, Ultegra, Dura-Ace.

The way in which the cranks are made and finished, along with the final weight, improves up through the range but the left hand arms remain interchangeable